# Remove field firing event click in afterLabelTextTpl

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I want to remove a form field, firing a click event in a afterLabelTextTpl.

However, I am not able to remove each field individually.

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ie7

The two span textfields has the same id. It must be so because the text fields are added dynamically from a standard textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot set the id individually, you can set the id to be unique by taking advantage of the way the XTemplate in *beforeLabelTextTpl* generates markup.  One way to do this is to append the field's generated id to the word '*icon*' (or some other prefix):

```
'<span id="icon{id}" ...
```

When rendered, this will replace {id} with the field's *id* property. Then you can refer to this unique id in the afterrender handler:

`var simboloEl = Ext.get("icon" + field.id);`

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1iek

Comment: Thanks chrisuae. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

This happen because you use same id's for both fields and when you click on first one it works for second one also.
Please Check Fiddle:https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ien

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
title: 'Simple Form',
bodyPadding: 5,
width: 350,

// The form will submit an AJAX request to this URL when submitted
url: 'save-form.php',

// Fields will be arranged vertically, stretched to full width
layout: 'anchor',
defaults: {
    anchor: '100%'
},

// The fields
defaultType: 'textfield',
items: [{
    fieldLabel: 'First Name',
    name: 'first',
    allowBlank: false,
    beforeLabelTextTpl: [
        '<tpl>',
            '<span style="color: red; cursor: pointer"; class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'required">X </span>',

        '</tpl>'
    ],
    listeners: {
         afterrender: function(field){
         var form = this.up('form');
         var simboloEl = Ext.get(field.getEl().dom.childNodes[0].getElementsByClassName('x-required')[0]);
         //var simboloEl = Ext.get("icon");
              if(simboloEl){
                   simboloEl.on("click", function () {
                        form.remove(field);
                   });
               }
         }
   }
},{
    fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
    name: 'last',
    allowBlank: false,
    beforeLabelTextTpl: [
        '<tpl>',
            '<span style="color: red; cursor: pointer"; class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'required">X </span>',

        '</tpl>'
    ],
    listeners: {
         afterrender: function(field){
         var form = this.up('form');
         var simboloEl = Ext.get(field.getEl().dom.childNodes[0].getElementsByClassName('x-required')[0]);
         //var simboloEl = Ext.get("icon1");
              if(simboloEl){
                   simboloEl.on("click", function () {
                        form.remove(field);
                   });
               }
         }
   }
}],
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay. Works great.